# Vb.net 2008 how to put images on crystal report from picturebox

Tags: crystal-reports, report, picturebox

Guys please help me on how to transfer image from picturebox to my crystal report imagebox?

Comment: my picturebox from my other form. now i want to transfer the image from my picturebox to crystal report image object

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the photo somewhere in the filesystem, with some sort of naming convention relative to your report so you can find it.

From there you can set the image path from the format menu in crystal as below.

[image]